# Extending an animation

Tags: animation

I have a mocap animation of a person jumping from a height of about 8 feet to ground level.
How do I make it appear that he/she is jumping from a height of 20 feet?

Comment: you probably need to go into the Graph Editor and change the location of the root bone on the Z axis

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The jump I have in mocap last 2 seconds. I would like it to last 4 seconds but not in slow motion if I stretched it out. I want the jump to look like he jumped from a height of 20 feet rather than eight feet.

Comment: [This short tutorial](https://youtu.be/aisWlTON1vU) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, Marty. I just started with Blender and found the short tutorial very helpful.

Comment: You're welcome.  CG Cookie can be a good source for short YouTube tutorials.